# Unable to convert and send JSON format to Avero format for Kafka topic using JMETER

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jmeter

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord

import org.apache.avro.Schema;

import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericContainer;

import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;

import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader;

import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;

import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;

import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter;

import org.apache.avro.io.Decoder;

import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;

import org.apache.avro.io.Encoder;

import org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory;

import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter;

def props = new Properties()

props.put("bootstrap.servers", "stage-kafka-2-client.rqs.svc.prod1-us-central1.gke.kaas-prod-us.gcp.extscloud.com:16512");

//props.put("kafka.topic.name", "rqs_stage1.pafx.Member.Sync_stg");

props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

//props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

//props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");

props.put("compression.type", "none");

props.put("batch.size", "16384");

props.put("linger.ms", "0");

props.put("buffer.memory", "33554432");

props.put("acks", "all");

props.put("send.buffer.bytes", "131072");

props.put("receive.buffer.bytes", "32768");

props.put("security.protocol", "SSL");

props.put("sasl.kerberos.service.name", "kafka");

props.put("sasl.mechanism", "GSSAPI");

props.put("ssl.key.password", "prmcert");

props.put("ssl.keystore.location", "C:/Users/slaksh36/JMETER/KeyStore/keystore.jks");

props.put("ssl.keystore.password", "prmcert");

props.put("ssl.keystore.type", "JKS");

props.put("ssl.truststore.location", "C:/Users/slaksh36/JMETER/KeyStore/truststore.jks");

props.put("ssl.truststore.password", "prmcert");

props.put("ssl.truststore.type", "JKS");

def schemaParser = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser();

def schema = schemaParser.parse(schemaJson)l;

def decoderFactory = new org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory();

def decoder = decoderFactory.jsonDecoder(schema, genericRecordStr);

def reader = new org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader()(schema);

def record = reader.read(null, decoder);

KafkaProducer\<String, String\> producer = new KafkaProducer\<String, String\>(props);

String schemaJson ='http://path/subjects/topic-name/versions/2';

String Message = '{\\"clientId\\": \\"\\",\\"deploymentChannel\\": \\"edata\\",\\"globalMemberId\\": \\"e4813805-f2dd-452e-b3e0-dbdd9fadbb32\\",\\"isActive\\": \\"\\",\\"isDeployable\\": \\"\\",\\"isDeployed\\": \\"\\",\\"marketSegment\\": \\"\\",\\"mbrCardId\\": \\"\\",\\"mbrHicMBI\\": \\"\\",\\"programYear\\": \\"\\",\\"providerGroupId\\": \\"\\",\\"providerId\\": \\"\\",\\"subClientSk\\": \\"\\"}';

producer.send(new ProducerRecord\<\>("topic name","key_val",message));

·        producer.close()
```

But still i am not able to send the topic in avero formate and it is throwing the below error Is there any additional depedencies need to be added apart from avero dependencies in JMETER Lib/ext folder. Please share some sample code to send avero schema data for Kafka topic in JMETER

I need to convert a JSON message to Avro so that I can send it to Kafka.I have the sample JSON request. Anyone help me please

Comment: Please format your code; remove the extra blank lines and the backslashes that look like you tried to quote html special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to escape quotation marks in your `Message` object.

In other words just replace this line:

```
String Message = '{\\"clientId\\": \\"\\",\\"deploymentChannel\\": \\"edata\\",\\"globalMemberId\\": \\"e4813805-f2dd-452e-b3e0-dbdd9fadbb32\\",\\"isActive\\": \\"\\",\\"isDeployable\\": \\"\\",\\"isDeployed\\": \\"\\",\\"marketSegment\\": \\"\\",\\"mbrCardId\\": \\"\\",\\"mbrHicMBI\\": \\"\\",\\"programYear\\": \\"\\",\\"providerGroupId\\": \\"\\",\\"providerId\\": \\"\\",\\"subClientSk\\": \\"\\"}';
```

with this one:

```
String Message = '{\n' +
        '  "clientId": "",\n' +
        '  "deploymentChannel": "edata",\n' +
        '  "globalMemberId": "e4813805-f2dd-452e-b3e0-dbdd9fadbb32",\n' +
        '  "isActive": "",\n' +
        '  "isDeployable": "",\n' +
        '  "isDeployed": "",\n' +
        '  "marketSegment": "",\n' +
        '  "mbrCardId": "",\n' +
        '  "mbrHicMBI": "",\n' +
        '  "programYear": "",\n' +
        '  "providerGroupId": "",\n' +
        '  "providerId": "",\n' +
        '  "subClientSk": ""\n' +
        '}'
```

and "your" "code" should start working for plain Strings.

If additionally you need to perform Avro serialization you need to:

1. Add [kafka-avro-serializer](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/kafka-avro-serializer) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (restart JMeter to pick it up)
2. Import `import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer;`
3. Create an Avro record from your payload like it's described in [Avro Schema Serializer and Deserializer](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html)

More information: [How to Do Kafka Testing With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/kafka-testing)